# Needing YTD Data from SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, between

I have looked around on this site quite a bit but am not able to get the code to work. I am needing the below code to pull from 2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31. I keep getting various errors when i try an adjust the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
WHERE e.[propertyname] IN ('PreviewTime','StageTime','WrapUpTime','AwaitingCallback')
 AND CAST(GetDate() as INT) - CAST(DATEADD(s,e.[odsoffset],e.[agenttimeUTC]) as INT) <= 90
```

Comment: What's the name of your date column on your e table? Is it `agenttimeUTC`?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: It looks like the original query you posted was doing some math against current date and some date in the column, that had to be less than or equal to 90 days...so I took a guess and made an attempted answer below...

Comment: you are right on. the math in the date is UTC against EST. So its taking 5 hours off the agenttimeutc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no SQL pro but I came across your question and thought maybe I'd learn something too.

Does something like this work?

```
WHERE e.[propertyname]
IN ('PreviewTime','StageTime','WrapUpTime','AwaitingCallback') 
  AND agenttimeUTC BETWEEN '2019/01/01' AND '2019/12/31';
```

## Edit1: I think I forgot some brackets on the column name, attempt#2:

```
WHERE e.[propertyname]
IN ('PreviewTime','StageTime','WrapUpTime','AwaitingCallback') 
  AND e.[agenttimeUTC] BETWEEN '2019/01/01' AND '2019/12/31';
```

Comment: That got it in that second one. Thanks so much for your help.